# Combo box filling common class in wpf C#

Tags: c#, wpf

I have created a common class for filling a combo box in WPF C#, but it does not work. I am looking for a common class for filling a combo box in WPF C#

```
     public void comboFill(ComboBox cmb, string procedureName, string dTable,   string dDisplay, string dValue)
    {
       try
        {
           using (SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(DBCon.conStr))
            {
                DataSet ds = new DataSet();
                SqlDataAdapter da = new SqlDataAdapter(procedureName, con);
                da.SelectCommand.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
                da.Fill(ds, dTable);
                cmb.DataSource = ds.Tables[dTable].DefaultView;
                cmb.DisplayMember = dDisplay;
                cmb.ValueMember = dValue;
                if (cmb.Items.Count > 0)
                {
                  cmb.SelectedIndex = 0;
                }
            }

        }
        catch (Exception exp)
        {
            MessageBox.Show(exp.Message);
        }
    }
```

Comment: Use cmb.ItemsSource = ds.Tables[dTable].DefaultView;

Comment: the given code is working

Comment: your code is already working?

Comment: You are using `System.Windows.Forms.ComboBox`, which is WinForms, not WPF. Use `System.Windows.Controls.ComboBox` instead.

Answer (score 0):

Are you sure you are using the Combobox correctly? I just checked that the combobox does not have the property *DataSource*. You can use the *ItemsSource* property to fill your box like so

```
cmb.ItemsSource = ds.Tables[dTable].DefaultView;
```

You could also Bind the same in XAML

```
<ComboBox ItemSource="{Binding MyData}" SelectedIndex=0/>
```

and in your code behind:

```
var MyData = ds.Tables[dTable].DefaultView;
```

Comment: I am used System.Windows.Forms.ComboBox. It contain  DataSource property.

Comment: Wrong Control. WPF has `System.Windows.Controls.ComboBox` It sould work then